# How do I get WordPress WP_Query->get_posts() on multiple categories to work?

Tags: wordpress

The docs discussing WP_Query() clearly state that this should work:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=tools,wordpress' );
```

However, if I use WP_Query's class method [->get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods):

```
$query->get_posts();
```

I only get the posts from `tools` (8 posts in total).

However, if I do:

```
while($query->have->posts()) { ... }
```

I can loop through all the posts (12 posts in total) as expected.

Is this by design, a design flaw, or a bug?

[EDIT] Here's the actual code I'm using:

```
// query
    $query = 'category_name=tools,wordpress&orderby=date&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1';
    $wpq = new WP_Query($query);

// loop-style version - shows all 12 posts
    while($wpq->have_posts())
    {
        $post = $wpq->next_post();
        echo "<p>{$post->post_title}</p>";
    }

// get_posts()-style version, only shows 8 posts from tools
    $posts = $wpq->get_posts();
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        echo "<p>{$post->post_title}</p>";
    }
```

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 4):

OK, I looked at the code inside the standalone function `get_posts()` and it provided the answer.

As with most things WordPress it's completely inconsistent!

You have to use `WP_Query->query();` and not `WP_Query->get_posts();`

```
// query
    $query      = 'category_name=tools,wordpress&orderby=date&order=desc&posts_per_page=-1';
    $wpq        = new WP_Query();

// new query() syntax has functionality of loop-style version but behaves like get_posts()
    $posts      = $wpq->query($query);
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        echo "<p>{$post->post_title}</p>";
    }

// debug
    printr($wpq);
```

Such a shame the WordPress API blows so badly.

[EDIT] Have just looked inside `->query()` and it uses `->get_posts()` internally. These simple calls should not all be having different behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are mixing things a little:

[get_posts()](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) - Retrieve list of latest posts or posts matching criteria.

You can use get_posts() by passing the argumets to it and it will alter the main query for you (which is not recommended)

[WP_Query](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) - The WordPress Query class.

This allows you to create new queries in the wp database.

get_posts() it's a method of WP_Query class

Check the links above they have examples on how to get posts by multiple categories. Also check Sandeep Kumar answer.

Your example can also be used:

```
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff,news' );
// The Loop ! there is no get_posts()!
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { ... }
}
```

An example using get_posts() is:

```
$args = array('category' => '1,2' ); //where 1 and 2 are the posts categories id's

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) { 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    ...
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also have a look at [pre_get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) documentation see if you can't use this one as it changes the query before it gets to the database, if you can use it, it will save you a trip to the database per page load.

Answer (score 0):

Show Posts From Several Categories

Display posts that have these categories, using category id:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
```

I think that would help you if not then can you provide me complete code so that i can check and provide you complete solution.

Comment: Nope - already tried that and it doesn't work with `$query->get_posts()` either. The only way it seems to get posts from all categories is to use `->have_posts()` / `->next_post()`

Comment: can you show me your complete code then i can provide you solution

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I edited the main post to include that, and also added an answer. From what I can tell, it's WordPress being consistently inconsistent.